# Parallel processing - `forking` fails under Mac OS 10.6.8

Tags: c, r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

It appears that `fork` fails under `Mac OS 10.6.8`. The algorithm is coded in R and I have mainly be using the [foreach](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) package for parallel processing. The code works perfectly well when run sequentially (`foreach` and `%do%`) but not when run in parallel (`foreach` and `%dopar%`) even though the processes run in parallel do NOT communicate.

I used `foreach` on this same machine a month ago and it worked fine. An update of the OS has been performed in the meantime.

**Error Messages**

I received several kinds of error messages that seems to come almost stochastically. Also the errors differ depending on whether the code is run from the terminal (either by copy-pasting in the `R` environment or with `R CMD BATCH`) or from the R console.

*When run on the Terminal*, I get

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'dp' not found"
```

*When run on the R console* I get *either*

```
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
....
<repeated many times when run on the R console>
```

*or*

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'dp' not found"
```

with the exact same code! Note that although this second error message is the same than the one received on the Terminal, the number of things that are printed (through the `print()` function) on the screen vastly differ!

**What I've tried**

- I updated the package `foreach` and I also restarting my computer but it did not quite help.
- I tried to `print` pretty much anything I could but it ended up being quite hard to keep track of what this algorithm is doing. For example, it often through the error about the missing object `dp` without executing the `print` statement at the line that precedes the call of the object `dp`.
- I tried to use `%dopar%` but registering only 1 CPU. The output did not change on the Terminal, but it changed on the Console. Now the console gives the exact same error, at the same time than the terminal.
- I made sure that several CPUs were in used when I ask for several CPUs.
- I tried to use `mclapply` instead of `foreach` and `registerDoMC()` instead of `registerDoParallel()` to register the number of cores.

**Extra-Info**

My version of R is `3.0.2 GUI 1.62 Snow Leopard build`. My machine has 16 cores.

Comment: this isn't an issue with your code, rather it is related to how parallel is implemented (`fork()` without `exec()`) [See here for more info](http://objectivistc.tumblr.com/post/16187948939/you-must-exec-a-core-foundation-fork-safety-tale). I remember issue impacting several R packages during the Snow Leopard/Mavericks transition and I am relatively certain I remember there being a work around, but can't remember what it was off the top of my head. Will see if I can dig it up!

Comment: Also, the reason you're seeing a different message when using R console is due to the way the fork process is referencing the R.gui (so at least that much of what you're seeing is expected)

Comment: have you tried saving your code as an R script and running it using `R CMD BATCH` from the terminal?

Comment: No, I haven't tried `R CMD BATCH`. Good point! I'll try that tomorrow morning (I don't have access to my code now). Thank you! So far, your comments sounds like "there's nothing I can do. I just have to make my own bash script or use some other package to run my code in paralell." Is that right?

Comment: it's possible that completely removing any interactive aspects of the code (by running it as a batch script) will do the trick. If not it's very likely that you will need to rework your code. Will be waiting on the update!

Comment: @scribbles Unfortunately, `R CMD BATCH myscript.R` it did not solve the problem. I get the same error message than when running `R` within the Terminal.

Comment: Darn! You may want to try asking over at Super User since this goes much deeper than the relatively straight forward R and C code you're running. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot anyway. Do you think that using `mclapply` or other methods might work? Or are they all dependent on `fork()` which is the ultimate issue?

Comment: it's very possible. I don't remember there being issues with doMC for example, but it's been a while since I've done any heavy lifting on a Snow Leopard machine.

Comment: Ok. I tried `doMC` but that didn't help either. On SuperUser, they seem to say that the question is a better fit on StackOverflow. I'll keep my question here and wait to eventually be migrated to SuperUser if other SO users agree.

Comment: Hope you're able to get this sorted out. I'll keep digging to see if I can remember what the work around was in the meantime.